# decision tree sklearn: prediction accuracy 100%

Tags: python-2.7, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, decision-tree

I am getting decision tree classifier accuracy 1.0 and only one node in decision tree output also only one element in confusion matrix. There is similar problem with Random Forest.

```
  import pandas
  import numpy 
  from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
  from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
  import sklearn.metrics

  data = pandas.read_csv('nesarc_pds.csv', low_memory=False)

#Setting variable to numeric.
data['CONSUMER'] = pandas.to_numeric(data['CONSUMER'], errors='coerce')
data['S2AQ16A'] = pandas.to_numeric(data['S2AQ16A'], errors='coerce')
data['S2DQ3C1'] = pandas.to_numeric(data['S2DQ3C1'], errors='coerce')
data['S2DQ3C2'] = pandas.to_numeric(data['S2DQ3C2'], errors='coerce')  
data['S2DQ4C1'] = pandas.to_numeric(data['S2DQ4C1'], errors='coerce')
data['S2DQ4C2'] = pandas.to_numeric(data['S2DQ4C2'], errors='coerce')
data['S2DQ1'] = pandas.to_numeric(data['S2DQ1'], errors='coerce')
data['S2DQ2'] = pandas.to_numeric(data['S2DQ2'], errors='coerce')
data['SEX'] = pandas.to_numeric(data['SEX'], errors='coerce')

 #subset data to the age 10 to 30 when started drinking 
 sub1=data[((data['S2AQ16A']>=10) & (data['S2AQ16A']<=30))]
 #Copy new DataFrame
sub2 = sub1.copy()

#Recording missing data
 sub2['S2AQ16A'] = sub2['S2AQ16A'].replace(99, numpy.nan)
 sub2['S2DQ3C1'] = sub2['S2DQ3C1'].replace(99, numpy.nan)
 sub2['S2DQ3C2'] = sub2['S2DQ3C2'].replace(9, numpy.nan)
 sub2['S2DQ4C1'] = sub2['S2DQ4C1'].replace(99, numpy.nan)
 sub2['S2DQ4C2'] = sub2['S2DQ4C2'].replace(9, numpy.nan)
 sub2['S2DQ1'] = sub2['S2DQ1'].replace(9, numpy.nan)
 sub2['S2DQ2'] = sub2['S2DQ2'].replace(9, numpy.nan)


  #creating a secondary variable for calculating sibling number.
  sub2['SIBNO'] = sub2['S2DQ3C1'] + sub2['S2DQ4C1']

#defining new variable for sibling drinking status by combining data of brothers and sisters
def SIBSTS(row):
if any([row['S2DQ3C2'] == 1, row['S2DQ4C2'] == 1]) :
    return 1       
elif all([row['S2DQ3C2'] == 2, row['S2DQ4C2'] == 2]) :
    return 0     
else :   
    return numpy.nan     
sub2['SIBSTS'] = sub2.apply(lambda row: SIBSTS (row),axis=1)  

#defining new variable for parent status status of drinking
def PRSTS(row):
    if any([row['S2DQ1'] == 1, row['S2DQ2'] == 1]) :
        return 1       
    elif all([row['S2DQ1'] == 2, row['S2DQ2'] == 2]) :
        return 0     
   else :   
        return numpy.nan     
   sub2['PRSTS'] = sub2.apply(lambda row: PRSTS (row),axis=1)  


  #recoding values for 'CONSUMER' into a new variable, DRSTS
  recode1 = {1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 0}
  sub2['DRSTS']= sub2['CONSUMER'].map(recode1)

 #recoding new values for SEX variable
 recode2 = {1: 1, 2: 0}
 sub2['GEN']= sub2['SEX'].map(recode2)

 data_clean = sub2.dropna()

 data_clean.dtypes
 data_clean.describe()

 #Modeling and Prediction

 #Split into training and testing sets

 predictors = data_clean[['S2AQ16A','SIBNO','SIBSTS','PRSTS','GEN']]

 targets = data_clean['DRSTS']

 pred_train, pred_test, tar_train, tar_test  =   train_test_split(predictors, targets, test_size=.4)

 print(pred_train.shape)
 print(pred_test.shape)
 print(tar_train.shape)
 print(tar_test.shape)

 #Build model on training data
 classifier=DecisionTreeClassifier()
 classifier=classifier.fit(pred_train,tar_train)

 predictions=classifier.predict(pred_test)

 print(sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix(tar_test,predictions))
 print(sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score(tar_test, predictions))

 #Displaying the decision tree
 from sklearn import tree
 #from StringIO import StringIO
 import io
 #from StringIO import StringIO 
 from IPython.display import Image
 out = io.BytesIO()
 tree.export_graphviz(classifier, out_file=out)
 import pydotplus
 graph=pydotplus.graph_from_dot_data(out.getvalue())
 Image(graph.create_png())
 graph.write_pdf("iris.pdf")
```

Output:
[image: Decision tree output which has only one node]

data set used in code- [nesar_pds](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B61fgGvJIlfibXJCaTR3NVp2UGs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After building a model on train dataset, you should use Test dataset for predicting the classifier Accuracy.

Error is in this line `predictions=classifier.predict(pred_train)`

It should be : `predictions=classifier.predict(pred_test)`

Comment: Thanks for helping @Darshan. I earlier used the code you mentioned but the result was same so I did this for checking purpose but forgot to correct it before posting here. Now I have edited this. I am facing same problem with Random Forest. I have shared the link for dataset in case if you want try to do it.

Comment: If it is so, then it shouldn't be the case.

Comment: I will try to find the cause and will let you know.

Comment: I ran your code and checked the dataset. Looks like your target variable **DRSTS** has only one value(i.e. 1). No other value. If you do _targets.describe_ you will find out. So it is very easy for any Classifier to predict accurate result as 1. Hence the Accuracy 1.

Comment: Thanks @Darshan You got it right. You pulled me out of frustration.

Comment: Welcome @ParasMani

Answer (score 0):

In your `print(sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score(tar_test, predictions))`, using it as `print(sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score(tar_test, predictions, normalize = False))`. According to [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score.html), it says: 'If False, return the number of correctly classified samples. Otherwise, return the fraction of correctly classified samples.' In this result, the number of correctly predicted samples is the same of the targets separated to test. Then, maybe the algorithm is predicting all correctly (what it is really strange).

Comment: There was mistake in data management process which resulted in only one category in target variable. @Darshan pointed this mistake.